# [k8s]I try to assign one pod to the normal node, and the others onto a spot node by using podAntiAffinity

Tags: kubernetes, affinity

I have 6 nodes,all of them have labels "group:emp",4 of them have labels "iKind:spot",2 of them have labels "ikind:normal".

I use the deployment yaml to assign one pod to the normal node and others on the spot node, but it didn't work.

I start to increase the num of the pod from 1 to 6,but when it comes to 2,all the pod are assigned on th spot node

````
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: pod-test
  namespace: emp
  labels:
    app: pod-test
spec:
  replicas: 2 
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pod-test
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate 
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1 
      maxUnavailable: 0 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pod-test
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: pod-test
          image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
          args: ["sh","-c","sleep 60000"]
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 10m
              memory: 100Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 200Mi
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
              - matchExpressions:
                  - key: group
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - emp
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - weight: 70
            preference:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: ikind
                operator: In
                values:
                - spot
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - weight: 100
            podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                - key: app
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - pod-test
              topologyKey: ikind
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - pod-test
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      ```
````

Comment: Could you explain what you want to achieve? You want each replica being deployed on another node? Or you just need a way to deploy those replicas on both spot and normal nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add the node prefer matchExpressions to normal and give weight 30,and it works.
In order to avoid the influence of the node nums,i change the weight of the normal and spot.

When replicas is 1,there is 1 pod in normal node

When replicas is 2,there is 1 pod in normal node and 1 pod in spot node

When replicas is 3,there is 2 pod in normal node and 1 pod in spot node

`preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - weight: 70
            preference:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: ikind
                operator: In
                values:
                - normal
          - weight: 30
            preference:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: ikind
                operator: In
                values:
                - spot`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy pods on all nodes then you have to change your preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution.

Change

```
preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - weight: 70
            preference:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: ikind
                operator: In
                values:
                - spot
```

to

```
preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
              - weight: 70
                preference:
                  matchExpressions:
                  - key: ikind
                    operator: In
                    values:
                    - spot
                    - normal
```

Now it will be deployed on both nodes, with `ikind:spot` and `ikind:normal`, before it was only spot.

I have tested it on 3 gke nodes and everything seems working just fine.

```
pod-test-54dc97fbcb-9hvvm   1/1     Running       gke-cluster-1-default-pool-1ffaf1b8-gmhb   <none>           <none>
pod-test-54dc97fbcb-k2hv2   1/1     Running       gke-cluster-1-default-pool-1ffaf1b8-gmhb   <none>           <none>
pod-test-54dc97fbcb-nqd97   1/1     Running       gke-cluster-1-default-pool-1ffaf1b8-7c25   <none>           <none>
pod-test-54dc97fbcb-zq9df   1/1     Running       gke-cluster-1-default-pool-1ffaf1b8-jk6t   <none>           <none>
pod-test-54dc97fbcb-zvwhk   1/1     Running        gke-cluster-1-default-pool-1ffaf1b8-7c25   <none>           <none>
```

---

It's well described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: with-node-affinity
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/e2e-az-name
            operator: In
            values:
            - e2e-az1
            - e2e-az2
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 1
        preference:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: another-node-label-key
            operator: In
            values:
            - another-node-label-value
  containers:
  - name: with-node-affinity
    image: k8s.gcr.io/pause:2.0
```

> This node affinity rule says the pod can only be placed on a node with a label whose key is kubernetes.io/e2e-az-name and whose value is either e2e-az1 or e2e-az2. In addition, among nodes that meet that criteria, nodes with a label whose key is another-node-label-key and whose value is another-node-label-value should be preferred.